# Addition of length of two words generates wrong answer(string0.length() + string1.length())

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

int main(){
    cout << "Welcome to the program!";
    cout << "\nWhat is your name? ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hi, " << name << ". ";
    cout << "Your name has " << name.length() << " letters!";
    cout << "\nWhat is your last name? ";
    string lastname;
    string *plastname;
    cin >> lastname;
    plastname = &lastname;
    cout << "Your full name is " << name.append(*plastname) << ".";
    cout << " Your full name has " << name.length() + lastname.length() << " letters!";
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the results:

- Welcome to the program!
- What is your name? adk
- Hi, adk. Your name has 3 letters!
- What is your last name? adkl
- Your full name is adkadkl. Your full name has 11 letters!

How 3 + 4 = 11?!

Comment: you are appending to the name, just use name variable for the number of letters (or don't append in the first place)

Comment: What use is the pointer `plastname`? What are you really using it for? What problem is it supposed to solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It might be for learning, but it shouldn't make a difference to the problem trying to be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you do `name.append(*plastname)` which really appends `lastname` into `name`, making `name` a string of length 7 (with your example input).

Then you print `name.length() + lastname.length()` which is equal to `7 + 4` (remember the previous append you did!), leading to the result of `11`.

Perhaps of appending `name` and `lastname`, you should print them separately? Like

```
cout << "Your full name is " << name << ' ' << lastname << ".\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You've appended `lastname` to `name` and then added them, that gives you a bigger value than expected

```
cout << "Your full name is " << name.append(*plastname) << ".";//You append here
cout << " Your full name has " << name.length() + lastname.length() << " letters!";//And then add here
```

Answer (score 1):

you just print name.length() instaed of name.length() + lastname.lenght() as you already appended the lastname to name.